# Execute a function when a Flex 3 App finishes execution

Tags: apache-flex, events

I am developing an lib which tracks user events, like button click, state change, module load and application finish.

My problem is how I can track the application finish event. I googled for it, but I found no good answer.

It is possible to use this kind of event?

Comment: Define "application finish event".  What specifically do you want to know about?

Comment: Lets do an analogy with JavaScript: I want to use an "onunload" event in Flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html), here is a good example:

[Browser Window Close Event and Flex Applications](http://www.flexer.info/2008/02/25/browser-window-close-event-and-flex-applications/)

Comment: Just what I was looking for, although I would prefer doing it without this "hacky" thing. Thank you very much.